# Jade is not working as expected not showing index.jade content

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

i am trying to use jade .i am trying to render a template in get request my code is

```
app.get('/promocode/generate-promocode',mw.authenticate,function(req,res)
    {  res.render('index1', {}); 
  });
```

my layout.jade file code is

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    block head
    title= title

    include layout/css
    include layout/headerjs

    body
      include header/main

      include layout/topbar

      .middle-content
        .container
          .wrapper
            block content

      include footer/main

      include layout/footerjs
```

and my index.jade file code is

```
extends layout

h1 Welcome to Marketplace 
h1 Welcome to Marketplace 
h1 Welcome to Marketplace 

h1 Welcome to Marketplace 

h1 Welcome to Marketplace 

h1 Welcome to Marketplace
```

when i goto page it is showing only layout.jade syntax no h1 heading with content "Welcome to Marketplace " . any suggestion how to show this heading tag in html page ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the same block in your index.jade which has to be inherited.

```
extends layout
block content
  h1 Welcome to Marketplace
```

Considering mismatch in filename in `res.render('index1', {});` and `index.jade` you gave as typo, this should solve your problem.